# How to create option aliases with boost::program_options?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-program-options

I would like to be able to have the possibility to create option aliases with `boost::program_options` that stores their arguments under the same key/label.

The architecture of my software uses different specialized option parsers depending on the value `argv[1]`.  However some options are shared, like my option `--inputs`.

```
inputOptions.add_options()
        ("--inputs",
         po::value< std::vector<std::string> >()->value_name("paths"),
         "List of files to edit.\n");
```

For compatibility with older version of the program, I would like to add to one of the sub-parsers a compatibility option `--input` that stores its argument(s) under "--inputs".  Ideally that option should take at most one argument instead of arbitrarily many.  However if you provide a solution that makes `--input` identical to `--inputs`, I guess it's fine too, as in this case positional options are sent to "--inputs" anyway.

Thank you for any help !

Comment: off the top of my head I think you'll have to do a manual check after the store/notify unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, that's unconvenient.  I was wishing something as easy as the `target` option in python's `argparse`...  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `extra_parser`(see [Non-conventional syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id-1.3.31.6.3) in the docs), i.e. parser that can be used to manipulates tokens from input before they are processed further. It can be used for things like translating `--run` into `--command=run` etc.

Extra parser is a functor that has the following signature:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string>(const std::string &s)
```

It should return option name in `pair::first` and (optional) option value in `pair::second`. Empty `pair::first` means that the extra parser has not parsed anything. Value (i.e. `pair::second`) can be empty - only option name has been parsed. If returned pair is valid then the name or name/value pair is used instead of parsing the original token via normal machinery.

First, we write aliasing function:

```
using OptionAliases = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

std::pair<std::string, std::string>
renameOptions(const std::string &token, const OptionAliases &aliases)
{
    auto rtoken(boost::make_iterator_range(token));

    // consume "--" prefix
    if (!boost::algorithm::starts_with(rtoken, "--")) { return { "", "" }; }
    rtoken.advance_begin(2);

    // find equal sign (returns iterator range)
    const auto eq(boost::algorithm::find_first(rtoken, "="));

    // extract option (between "--prefix" and "="/end()) and map it to output
    const auto faliases(aliases.find(std::string(rtoken.begin(), eq.begin())));
    if (faliases == aliases.end()) { return { "", "" }; }

    // return remapped option and (optionally) value after "="
    return std::make_pair(faliases->second
                          , std::string(eq.end(), rtoken.end()));
}
```

It simply splits input token into `--`, `name`, `=`, `value` (no value if there is no `=` sign) and if the name is found in the provided alias mapping it returns `(remapped-name, value)`.

Then, we create the parser itself, using lambda:

```
boost::program_options::ext_parser optionAlias(OptionAliases &&aliases)
{
    return [aliases{std::move(aliases)}](const std::string &token)
    {
        return renameOptions(token, aliases);
    };
}
```

(Needs at least C++14, for C++11 change to `return [aliases](con...`)

You can plug this parser into cmdline parser:

```
parser.extra_parser(optionAlias({{"mark.twain", "samuel.clemens"}
                                  , {"lewis.caroll", "charles.dodgson"}}));
```

Now, in the example above, both `--mark.twain` and `--samuel.clemens` will point to `vars["samuel.clemens"]` and both `--lewis.caroll` and `--charles.dodgson` will point to `vars["charles.dodgson"]`.

**Caveats**:

- Works only for command line parser.
- Expects `allow_long` style (long options with `--` prefix). Can be changed in the code.
- Expects `long_allow_adjacent` style (values allowed in one token using `=`). Can be changed in the code, as well.
- If there is any non-option token that parses as `--alias` then it is translated as well since there is no context. No way to circumvent.

  Example: If there's an option with name `name` that expects value and `long_allow_next` style is used, then `--name=--mark.twain` will be parsed as option `name` with value `--mark.twain` (as expected) while `--name --mark.twain` will be parsed as option `name` with value `samuel.clemens`.

  Short of that, it works as expected.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the form `po::value<...>(&variable)`? The value of the option is saved directly to the variable after parsed. You can then add two options `--input` and `--inputs` pointing to the same variable. Additionally, you'd probably have to check that only one of the two options is used and, otherwise, show an error message.

I hope I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.  However the variables_map is thrown around in many places in the code, so and you solution is not really usable for me.  however if I ever refactor the code, I might use that.

Answer (score 0):

By default boost::program_options allows the prefix of a long option to match that option. So the code you have written will already accept `--input` as an alias for `--inputs`.