# boost program_options disable no spaces in command line

Tags: boost-program-options

I am trying to fix a problem in a program using boost program_options to process the command line.

There are two different commands starting with s. One is defined in add_options as something like this:
"start,s",po::value()

The other is defined something like this:
"stop", po::value()

If the command line is typed correctly, for example "--stop x", everything works fine. If the user forgets to put in one of the hyphens, like this "-stop x", program_options believes that the user is performing the start command ("-s top") and returns a nonsense error. Fixing the error is not a problem but what would happen if "-s top" was a legal command? In which case, a simple, minor, and understandable error on the part of the user could have disastrous consequences. Not exactly user friendly.

I think the best thing would be to force there to be a space between the command and argument, but don't see any way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`extra_parser` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065383/how-to-create-option-aliases-with-boostprogram-options). You get the `"-stop"` input, and have a first chance to parse it.

To require a space after short options, you'd add a hidden option `--error-missing_space` to your `po::options_description`. In `extra_parser`, check if the input matches the regex `$-[^-][^ ]`. If so, you return `{"error-missing_space", ""}`. This will end up calling the notifier of your `--error-missing_space` option.

If you want, you can squirrel the original argument in the second return value of  `extra_parser`. I.e, you rewrite `-stop` to `--error-missing_space=stop`, and your `--error-missing_space` notifier can print out exactly where the space was missing.